# function parameter not getting assigned

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Calling a function that wraps stopping an IIS app pool.  Why would the 'Name' parameter for Stop-WebAppPool have an issue?  The only thing I can see is since its inside a script block?

error:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null.
>   Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the
>   command  again.

```
function StopAppPool() {
    param( 
        [string] $siteName = "",
        [string] $serverName = ""
    );


    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -ScriptBlock { Stop-WebAppPool -Name $siteName }   

}

# -- entry here
StopAppPool -siteName "my.test-server.web" -serverName "DEV-MYTEST1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Name` is empty because you can't reference variables directly inside of the Script Block. Using `Invoke-Command`, you must pass in your `$siteName` into the Script Block as an argument, and receive it as a parameter inside the Script Block. Something like this:

```
...

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -ArgumentList $siteName -ScriptBlock {
    Param($siteName)
    Stop-WebAppPool -Name $siteName
    }   

...
```